# True or false? - Let $A_1 , A_2 , A_3 , ... $ be any sets, then...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

if $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}$ ~ $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}$ , then $A_i$~$A_j$ for all $i,j\in \{1,2,...\} $. 
Intuitively, and after trying for a while to come up with a counter example, I think it's  true, but I'm not being able to prove it formally, I know that there is an one-to-one and onto function between $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}$ and $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}$, but I'm not being able to use it to create onto and one to one functions between $A_i$ and $A_j$ for every $j,i\in \{1,2,...\} $. 

Any help or explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Use Schroder-Bernstein Theorem.

Comment: HINT: $$|A_i|\le\left|\bigcup_{n\ge 1}A_n\right|=\left|\bigcap_{n\ge 1}A_n\right|\le|A_i|$$ for each $i\in\Bbb Z^+$, where $|X|\le|Y|$ means that there is an injection from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for the hint, that clears it, i got some questions, I can intuitively understand that $A_i$ is less equal than the Union and greater equal than the intersection, do I need to prove it?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott another question is: this proves that $A_i$~$A_i$ , that does imply that $A_i$~$A_j$?

Comment: The fact that $A_i\subseteq\bigcup_{n\ge 1}A_n$ makes it easy to write down an injection: the identity map will do. The other inequality is similar. \\ What it proves is that $A_i\sim\bigcup_{n\ge 1}A_n$ for every $i\in\Bbb Z^+$. (That’s what Kavi Rama Murthy was getting at.) And **that** shows that $A_i\sim A_j$ for all $i,j\in\Bbb Z^+$.

Comment: Thank you for the help